# Should all TestMethods remain in same TestClass?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have just begun to write Visual Studio unit tests for a MVC application.

I have created several TestClasses, and TestMethods inside them.

[image]

But when I use test explorer, I could see test methods from only one class.

[image]

And those come from this class, does that mean that I should have `one and only one` TestClass in one testproject?

```
[TestClass]
public class AndIHave_NoLakshyaDefined
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void IShouldBeAbleTo_SetLakshya()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AndIShouldBeAbleTo_DoThat()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run ALL tests of your test project? Are all classes/method you would like to test marked with the test attribute?

Comment: Can you paste some class/methods that don't show up?  A common gotcha is forgetting that both class and methods must be public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can have as much test classes as you want inside your test project.

Check some things:

- Your test classes and test methods are public.
- You have built the entire solution without errros.

If both these statements are true and you still can't see all tests, please provide some examples of tests that you can't see.